# using platform specific cordova plugins in the same codebase?

Tags: cordova, ember.js, cordova-plugins, ember-cli

Is there any way to use cordova-cli (specifically ember-cli-cordova) in such a way that different platform builds use different plugins?

I need to implement in-app payments in a ember app build using ember-cli for both android and ios (there is no x-platform plugin at the moment).

If not, any tips on preferred workflows for getting around the problem would be welcomed!